# Firebase: Querying by Key?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've looked around - I don't see any question similar so I'll ask?
How do I query by key value successfully?

I have a database composed like the following:

```
{
 Data {
  ABC_1 {
  ...
  }
  ABC_2 {
  ...
  }
  ABC-D_3 {
  ...
  }
  BCA_4 {
  ...
  }
 }
}
```

Now the user submits some input - lets suppose ABC, and I want my query to return everything that starts with ABC_.

So what I did is order by key, and then make a request like follows:

```
var data = database.ref('Data').orderByKey().startAt(brandholder);
data.on('value', this.gotdata.bind(this), this.errorData);
```

But its returning to me every child.
What am I doing wrong here?

Oh in case you are wondering how I have such a data structure.
I have a large dataset, and turned it into the JSON format you see above.
It is very large to load into browser (many 20+ mb), so I'd rather query the necessary results as opposed to loading it everytime.

Is there possibly a better way to do this?
I'm using Angular.

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase query operator is called `startAt` and not `startWith`. So in your current query Firebase orders all child nodes by their key, then finds the first one whose key starts with `ABC_`, and then returns all children after that.

To build a query that gets all child nodes whose keys start *with* a certain substring, you'll need to use a combination of `startAt` and `endAt`:

```
var data = database.ref('Data').orderByKey().startAt("ABC_").endAt("ABC_\uf8ff");
```

The `endAt("ABC_\uf8ff")` in this query ensures that Firebase stops returning child nodes once it reaches the end of the ones starting with `ABC_` (as `\uf8ff` is the last Unicode character).

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood how .startAt and .endAt works.

I for some reason thought they were only querying those objects that started with the particular sequence that I submitted. But I understand now that they started the query from a ordered list.

If this is how Firebase works. Would it be better to adjust by JSON tree to not have the _id component, and instead list that as a value within the key?

Then I could just use the .equalsTo.

The solution you gave works beautifully - with my base knowledge I would never have known about the \uf8ff. Time to learn UniCode.